# Nolock not working inside linked query

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, linked-server

I am trying to access a linked query with (nolock) option, but it is throwing me error, below is my query.

```
SELECT * FROM openquery(testengine , 'SELECT * FROM employee WITH(nolock)')
```

The following error is returned:

> an error occurred while preparing the query "my query" for execution
>   against OLEDB provider "ORAOLEDB.oracle" for linked server

Comment: what does an error say?

Comment: an error occurred while preparing the query "my query"  for execution against OLEDB provider "ORAOLEDB.oracle" for linked server.

Comment: have you created linked server first? if not, see this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2013/10/02/creating-a-linked-server-for-oracle-in-64bit-sql-server/

Comment: if i remove that no lock my query works fine

Comment: try to create a view in the linked server with the `WITH(nolock)` clause and then query it normally

Comment: i tried it , there's no luck with view too..

Comment: From your error message, it looks like the linked server is Oracle. `OPENQUERY` queries must be written in the SQL dialect of the target system, and `NOLOCK` is not supported Oracle syntax - hence the error.

Comment: @EdHarper looks like a worthy answer to me.

Answer (score 2):

From your error message, it looks like the linked server is Oracle. [`OPENQUERY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx) queries are executed on the target server, and so must be written in the SQL dialect of the target system.

`NOLOCK` is not supported Oracle syntax - hence the error.